# How to save text along with styling from RichTextFX StyleClassedTextArea?

Tags: javafx, richtextfx

I need to save the text from StyleClassedTextArea in a variable along with its styling so that i can populate the StyleClassedTextArea with the same styled text later

```
String text = styleClassedTextArea.getText();
```

This only saves the plain text

I need to populate the StyleClassedTextArea with the saved styled text like this

```
styleClassedTextArea.insertText(0, text );
```